# How to catch COM object exception?

Tags: c#, com, .net-1.1

I get the error:

> COM object with CLSID {88578679-272B-40C0-B1FD-C3409381A450} is either not valid or not registered.

And I know it is because I need to register my DLL using *regsvr32*. I was wondering if I can catch the exception for this error, so that I can log to the user to use *regsvr32* to register the DLL's.

Or must I simply catch all the exceptions?

Comment: The same way as any other exception is caught. The type is dah-dah: `COMException`.

Comment: Don't it be useful to register dll by your app itself?

Comment: do you have any Try catch code in your exiting code.. here is a site as well to look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the exception will be thrown the very first time you try to reference the COM object with your code. That is where you should put the try catch block, and you can just use the basic "Exception" type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
catch(COMException comEx)
{
   // do something
}
```

Although that's not the *only* reason a `COMException` may be thrown, so you may be chasing red herrings if you *assume* that the problem is always that the class is not registered.

Comment: While such a silly question, +1 for the answer and mentioning that COMException covers *alot* of ground. The ErrorCode can be used to refine it further.